# Stop json.Marshal() from stripping trailing zero from floating point number

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I got the following problem:
My golang program converts some information into JSON.
For example it results in the following json:

```
{
   "value":40,
   "unit":"some_string"
}
```

The problem is the "input" for value is 40.0 and the marshalling strips the trailing zero. It would be no problem if the EPL which reads the JSON would be able to read 40 as float without the .0

So the JSON output should look like:

```
{
   "value":40.0,
   "unit":"some_string"
}
```

Is there a possibility to "stop" json.Marshal() from removing the zero?

Edit: Value **must** be a Float

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@icza provided a good answer, but just to offer another option, you can define your own float type and define your own serialization for it. Like this

```
type KeepZero float64

func (f KeepZero) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if float64(f) == float64(int(f)) {
        return []byte(strconv.FormatFloat(float64(f), 'f', 1, 32)), nil
    }
    return []byte(strconv.FormatFloat(float64(f), 'f', -1, 32)), nil
}

type Pt struct {
    Value KeepZero
    Unit  string
}

func main() {
    data, err := json.Marshal(Pt{40.0, "some_string"})
    fmt.Println(string(data), err)
}
```

This results in `{"Value":40.0,"Unit":"some_string"} <nil>`. [Check it out in playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/iqs2ZtAZ_UB)

Answer (score 10):

By default floating point numbers are rendered without a decimal point and fractions if its value is an integer value. The representation is shorter, and it means the same number.

If you want control over how a number appears in the JSON representation, use the [`json.Number`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number) type.

Example:

```
type Pt struct {
    Value json.Number
    Unit  string
}

func main() {
    data, err := json.Marshal(Pt{json.Number("40.0"), "some_string"})
    fmt.Println(string(data), err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zW1DbZb9BT0)):

```
{"Value":40.0,"Unit":"some_string"} <nil>
```

If you have a number as a `float64` value, you may convert it to `json.Number` like this:

```
func toNumber(f float64) json.Number {
    var s string
    if f == float64(int64(f)) {
        s = fmt.Sprintf("%.1f", f) // 1 decimal if integer
    } else {
        s = fmt.Sprint(f)
    }
    return json.Number(s)
}
```

Testing it:

```
f := 40.0
data, err := json.Marshal(Pt{toNumber(f), "some_string"})
fmt.Println(string(data), err)

f = 40.123
data, err = json.Marshal(Pt{toNumber(f), "some_string"})
fmt.Println(string(data), err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UM7o9sO-i0z)):

```
{"Value":40.0,"Unit":"some_string"} <nil>
{"Value":40.123,"Unit":"some_string"} <nil>
```

The other direction, if you want the `float64` value of a `json.Number`, simply call its [`Number.Float64()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number.Float64) method.

Comment: Is there a way to do this when the JSON structure is only known at runtime, i.e when marshalling to `map[string]interface{}`?

Comment: @Jack You can "swap" `float64` values in the map with "pre-rendered" `json.Number` values, and then marshal the map.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to marshal a `map[string]interface{}` with float values f.x `1.0` to JSON as `1.0`. I solved it by adding a custom Marshal function for a custom float type and then replace the floats in the map with the custom type:

```
type customFloat float64

func (f customFloat) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if float64(f) == math.Trunc(float64(f)) {
        return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%.1f", f)), nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(float64(f))
}

func replaceFloat(value map[string]interface{}) {
    for k, v := range value {
        switch val := v.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            replaceFloat(val)
        case float64:
            value[k] = customFloat(val)
        }
    }
}
```

Then replace all float64 nodes:

```
replaceFloat(myValue)
bytes, err := json.Marshal(myValue)
```

This will print the floats like `1.0`

Comment: This is great for many cases.

Unfortunately it does not handle a nested array-of-floats. They will not be converted to special float type

Answer (score 0):

```
  type MyFloat float64
  func (mf MyFloat) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {                                                          
      return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%.1f", float64(mf))), nil                                                     
  }
```

used like this

```
 type PricePoint struct {
     Price    MyFloat   `json:"price"`
     From     time.Time `json:"valid_from"`
     To       time.Time `json:"valid_to"`
 }
```

Replace the `1` in `"%.1f"` with what ever precision you need

Answer (score -2):

Save the value as a string and cast it back if you need it.

Comment: The idea is not bad, forgot to mention: the json is posted to a platform that does not allow strings as value

Comment: Updated my original post