# Preserve trailing zero when using json.Unmarshal()

Tags: json, go

This is not a duplicate of [Stop json.Marshal() from stripping trailing zero from floating point number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446730/stop-json-marshal-from-stripping-trailing-zero-from-floating-point-number) because I wish to **un**marshal (i.e. parse the JSON-encoded data).

The trailing `.0` is stripped out in the code below: https://play.golang.org/p/jrQ3OSvoTt5.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var result map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"foo": 1.0}`), &result)
    
    // map[foo:1]
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

The structure of the JSON is only known at runtime, so I must parse it into `map[string]interface{}`.

While I appreciate that `1` and `1.0` are numerically equivalent, I need to be able to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @jimb As stated in the question "while I appreciate that 1 and 1.0 are numerically equivalent, I need to be able to distinguish between the two."

Comment: @Jack according to the JSON spec, they are the same thing. If you need to distinguish them in a valid JSON document, you should consider using strings instead.

Comment: @Adrian, which JSON spec is that? This doesn't say anything about them being the same thing:  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159

Comment: Yes, I mis-spoke as well, because actual precision is implementation defined, however most implementation use floats to be compatible with ECMAScript.

Comment: @BurakSerdar the spec you linked to. There aren't distinct "integer" and "float" types, only a single "number" type; since `1` and `1.0` represent the same number, and there is no distinguishing between integers and floats in JSON, they are the same as far as JSON is concerned, according to the spec.

Comment: @Adrian, The spec does not say that. It talks about interoperability issues, etc. but it never says 1 and 1.0 are different. It is left to the implementation. If you unmarshal to float64, they are the same. If you unmarshal to a json.Number, they are not.

Comment: @BurakSerdar the spec gives one numeric type, `Number`. In what way, per the spec, do you see any differentiation between the `Number` `1.0` and the `Number` `1`? The spec doesn't *need* to explicitly say "1.0 and 1 are the same"; that level of explicit specificity would make the spec a thousand pages long. It gives a type spec, and there is only one numeric type, therefore there is no distinction in JSON between `1.0` and `1`; they are both the `Number` representation of the whole number 1.

Comment: @Adrian, the spec is talking about a `Number`, not a numeric value. It explicitly states that the interpretation of the number as a numeric value is implementation dependent. As evident from my answer, the two values *are* different in Go, depending on how you decode it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default unmarshaler uses float64. You have to use a `Decoder` with `UseNumber`, then the numbers will be unmarshaled as `json.Number` and you can process them.

```
func main() {
    var result map[string]interface{}
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(`{"foo": 1.0}`))
    dec.UseNumber()
    dec.Decode(&result)

    // map[foo:1]
    fmt.Println(result)
    fmt.Println(result["foo"].(json.Number).String())
    fmt.Println(result["foo"].(json.Number).Float64())
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Other than using `strings.Contains` is there a way to check if `json.Number` contains a decimal? Type assertions don't get me anywhere if the number has an explicit zero fractional part (i.e. trailing `.0`). Both `Float64()` and `Int64()` assert without error.